# Get price of the in-app purchase on windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, windows-8.1

How to get price of in-app purchase on windows 8.1?

Because I use this code:

```
if (!(listing.ProductListings[nid].FormattedPrice == String.Empty))
                    {
                        file.Harga = listing.ProductListings[nid].FormattedPrice;
                    }
```

The application straight out and display an error message like the following picture:
[image: error message]

Comment: Are you sure that the ProductListings contains the product id?

Comment: yes, it's contain product id. nid is a products id.

Comment: My question was weather this ProductListings contains the product id that you specify. It seams that you specify Id that is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are calling the apis correctly.

You are getting a "KeyNotFoundException". This means the key you're looking for isn't in the dictionary. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx

To find out which products are available, either iterate through your listings with a foreach-loop or use TryGetValue to access a certain value.